# Using a non-isolate scoped directive multiple times on a page

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

The current problem I am facing is the following: 
I have 2 directives

- DateTimePicker (own code)
- Watermark (3rd party)

The problem is that both directives need to work on the same input. So both directives cannot have an isolate scope.

Due to that reason I changed the **DateTimePicker**-directive to not have an isolate scope. The problem now is that if I have multiple DateTimePicker-directives on a page, only the last one will function properly (showing, hiding, binding the value).

Is there any elegant way to solve this issue without rewriting the Watermark-directive?

plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/d6RxkLG60SkyFvuQpWUp?p=preview

```
//as you can see in the plunk,
//both vm.model1 and vm.model2 are updated at the same time.
```

*Edit: I added a link to the punker*

Comment: Can you add plunker?